# Block an insert call or convert it to upsert in trigger

Tags: apex, dml, upsert

Zapier connects our forms to our Salesforce instance. However, Zapier does not provide an upsert call as a way to insert a record, only insert and update. This means we have to use up more of our allowance of "tasks" to first search for the record, then decided whether we should insert or update.

I want to reduce my task usage, and I must make an upsert call.

Can I block the insert from Zapier in a trigger, without the block being registered as a failed transaction to Zapier, to subsequently continue the operation as an upsert?

Comment: I think you need to create a custom rest service to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't, at least, not directly. You'd have to allow the transaction to complete, perhaps by merging the record into the existing record, or by performing an upsert and an asynchronous delete afterwards. All of this is pretty hacky, though; it'd be better to find a tool suited to your needs, rather than try to make Salesforce work with the tool.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected this would be the case.